# Ubuntu 10.04 server delay when POST to mySQL

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 Server and for some reason it always seems to exhibit an intermittent delay whenever performing CRUD operations on the mySQL database.  Most `Post` commands are executed within a normal amount of milliseconds, but when there is a delay it always seems to be for about 4.5 seconds.  This is not a busy, public server so it shouldn't be a matter of server load being the problem.  The best way for you to understand what I am trying to explain is for me to show you.  So without further delay, please take a quick look at these couple of short videos:

[short server delay video 1](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=4k9qtg&s=6)

[short server delay video 2](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2jfbn8p&s=6)

Can anyone give me any ideas why this is happening and what to try to resolve it?